# Issue with jquery-ui dialog auto height

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm having an issue adjusting the jquery-ui dialog height.  I am using version 1.10.3.
My dialog initialization looks like this:

```
 $('#dlgOnlineChange').dialog({        
    autoResize: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: '800',
    height: 'auto',
    resizable: false,        
    title: "Details"
});
```

When the dialog opens, height is set to auto but the dialog is not tall enough to show all of the data.  The dialog is not opened until all of the data is loaded so i'm not sure why this would be the case.
If i try to hard code a height like this:

```
 $('#dlgOnlineChange').dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: '800',
    height: '900',
    resizable: false,        
    title: "Details"
});
```

The dialog is high enough but it still shows the scroll bar but only on the top portion of the dialog:

[image]

My modal markup looks like this:

```
<div id="dlgOnlineChange" title="" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateOnlineChange", "Contact", FormMethod.Post, new { area = "Admin", id = "frmDlgOnlineChange", @role = "form" }))
        {
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <b>ID</b><br />
                        <div id="divId"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <b>NAME</b><br /><div id="divAName"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <b>EFFECTIVE DATE</b><br /><div id="divEffectiveDate"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <b>SUBMITTED DATE</b><br /><div id="divDateSubmitted"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row currentinfo">
                        <div class="row">CURRENT INFORMATION</div>
                        <div class="row">
                            HOME ADDRESS:<br /><div id="divCurrentHomeAddress"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            OFFICE ADDRESS:<br /><div id="divCurrentOfficeAddress"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            MAILING ADDRESS:<br /><div id="divCurrentMailingAddress"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            PUBLIC ADDRESS:<br /><div id="divCurrentPublicAddress"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            PHONE(S):<br />
                            <div class="row">
                                Home:&nbsp;<span id="divCurrentHomePhone"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                Office:&nbsp;<span id="divCurrentOfficePhone"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                Mobile:&nbsp;<span id="divCurrentMobilePhone"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                Fax:&nbsp;<span id="divCurrentFax"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                Other:&nbsp;<span id="divCurrentOtherPhone"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            EMAIL ADDRESS(ES):<br />
                            <div class="row">
                                Primary:&nbsp;<span id="divCurrentPrimaryEmail"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                Secondary:&nbsp;<span id="divCurrentSecondaryEmail"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                Other:&nbsp;<span id="divCurrentOtherEmail"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row submittedInfo">
                    <div class="row">SUBMITTED INFORMATION</div>
                    <div class="row">
                        HOME ADDRESS:<br /><div id="divSubmittedHomeAddress"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        OFFICE ADDRESS:<br /><div id="divSubmittedOfficeAddress"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        MAILING ADDRESS:<br /><div id="divSubmittedMailingAddress"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        PUBLIC ADDRESS:<br /><div id="divSubmittedPublicAddress"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        PHONE(S):<br />
                        <div class="row">
                            Home:&nbsp;<span id="divSubmittedHomePhone"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            Office:&nbsp;<span id="divSubmittedOfficePhone"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            Mobile:&nbsp;<span id="divSubmittedMobilePhone"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            Fax:&nbsp;<span id="divSubmittedFaxPhone"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            Other:&nbsp;<span id="divSubmittedOtherPhone"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        EMAIL ADDRESS(ES):<br />
                        <div class="row">
                            Primary:&nbsp;<span id="divSubmittedPrimaryEmail"></span><br />
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            Secondary:&nbsp;<span id="divSubmittedSecondaryEmail"></span><br />
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            Other:&nbsp;<span id="divSubmittedOtherEmail"></span><br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me figure out what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the window height instead:

```
$('#dlgOnlineChange').dialog({        
autoResize: true,
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
width: '800',
height: window.innerHeight,
resizable: false,        
title: "Details"});
```

Comment: This does the same thing as when i hard coded it to be height: 900, like the image in my post.  It gives the dialog more height but the contents do not expand past where the scrollbar stops

Comment: The real issue here was that there was a max-height set on modal-body.  .modal-body{ max-height:900px; overflow: auto; overflow-x:hidden;}  Increasing this max-height fixed my issue

Comment: Great! I hope it has been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I added position to my dialog initialization and it's sizing correctly now.   I also removed the height. Dialog initialization now looks like this:

```
$('#dlgOnlineChange').dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: '800',        
    resizable: false,        
    title: "Details",
    position: [($(window).width() / 2), 150]
});
```

I'm not sure why this works but i'm going with it for now.  I'm definitely open for better solutions if there's one out there.

Comment: Actually this didn't work.  The dialog was just scrolled to the bottom and i thought everything had fit but didn't notice the data on the top wasn't showing